# How to create multiple subplots, with the date column as the x -axis and the sum of the rest columns as the y-axis?

Tags: python, plot, char, plotly, subplot

I have this dataframe and I want to create a subplot for each exercise, depicting the sum of sets for each date in a trend line format.

This is the jupyter notebook : https://github.com/TheoPallis/Portfolio/blob/Site/Workout_Project/Workout.ipynb.

I have tried the following code :

```
 grp = df.groupby('Date').sum()
    melted = pd.melt(grp, var_name="Exercise", ignore_index=False)
    print(melted)
        px.line(melted,
            y='value',
            facet_col='Exercise',
            facet_col_spacing=0.1)
```

but I get this unelegant output. [image].

Ideally, the sublots would be arranged in a grid format :

First row : 3 subplots
Second row : 3 subplots
Third row : 2 subplots (and 1 blank?)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) on subplots yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
grp = data.groupby('Date').sum()
melted = pd.melt(grp, var_name="Exercise", ignore_index=False)

# define exercises list
exercises = melted.reset_index()
exercises = set(melted['Exercise'])

# define plot grid
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 12))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

# loop over grid and exercises
for exercises, ax in zip(exercises, axs.ravel()):
    melted[melted["Exercise"] == exercises].plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: This look very much like my ideal output. A couple of pointers :

1) I would like for  the y axis for each chart to start at 0.


2) I would like for the x axis to be on a date ascending order. 

Thank you for your answer! 

(Ps I can't upvote you yet, due to new account limitations)